# Upgrade 19 to 20 error - Tilting black screen with top-left cursor before login

Tags: grub2, upgrade, 20.04, graphics, boot-repair

PC: Lenovo X201 - 2010
Intel Core i5 vPro
BIOS: 1.16 2010
Embedded controller version - 1.09
GNU GRUB - 2.04
Linux 4.15.0-119

**Description:**
I have recently tried to upgrade from **Ubuntu 19.04 to 20.04** via command line on terminal. The process went okay until it shot down not initializing after the completion. I had to turn it on again with On/off button. After this I was never able to login again.

So I am not sure which version is currently on. Accessing the GRUB menu and clicking on Advanced Options I have these following options:

- *Ubuntu, Linux 4.15.0-119 generic and recovery mode*
- *Ubuntu, Linux 4.15.0-118 generic and recovey mode*
- *Ubuntu, Linux 4.15.0-117 generic and recovery mode*

None of them goes past the black screen with top-left cursor.

After the booting process, the Ubuntu Logo appears (19.04 logo) and buffers only to the second dot, and then goes tilting - like on and off - until it reaches a static point with a cursor on top left.

During this, when I forcefully reboot - ctrl+alt+del - the Ubuntu 20.04 logo appears right before the computer reboots.

This is what I already tried - *Failed attempts*:

Removed ‘quiet splash’ on GRUB ‘e’ command line and added ‘nomodeset’ on linux line as a temporary fix. *Result:* failed to disable graphics turbo

Did the same process on GRUB > Recovery mode > Root > with the command: ‘sudo nano /etc/default/grub’ and then ‘update-grub’. **Result**: failed to disable graphics turbo

Downloaded missing packages on GRUB with root access. **Result**: same tilting black screen followed by the top-left cursor.

Some options after a research that I couldn’t manage to do:

Change boot priority on BIOS - my Bios does not have the security PPT to begin with.

Reinstall NVIDIA drivers - I don’t know how to do that, but when I put on command as root on GRUB - ‘$ sudo lshw -c video’ , i got this

VGA compatible controller - core processor integrated graphics controller

Some additional troubleshooting I did:

Hard Disk Drive diagnosis program - main hard disk drive

Result: error code 0100: speed test failed

Any feedback is going to be very helpful, thanks a lot !

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04's intended upgrade path was to 19.10 and not 20.04. You've also mentioned non-19.04 kernels as options which doesn't match your description. You should stick to LTS releases if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months as non-LTS releases require (19.04 was not a LTS release).

Comment: You've likely waited to long to be able to upgrade this installation to a supported release. 19.04 has been EOL for so long that even the following standard release, 19.10 has also gone EOL. Skipping releases is not supported.  As such, it's not likely that you will be able to successfully upgrade this system to a supported release.  Ubuntu 20.04 is a **LTS** release which will be supported for 5 years in the case of the default flavor and 3 years in the case of other flavors.  I suggest that you backup what you need from this install and cleanly install 20.04.